# Why does the transformation of my dataset from long-format to wide-format not work?

Tags: format, long-format-data, wide-format-data

I´m currently trying to convert my dataset from its current wide-format to a long format.
But it won't work, here my code:
dat_oZ2 = pivot_longer(data=dat_oZ2, cols=c(VN01,VN03, VN05,VN06,VN07,VN08,VN09,VN10,VN11,VN12,VN13,VN14,VN15,VN16,VN17,VN18,VN19,VN20,VN21,VN22,VN23,VN24,VN25,VN26,VN27,VN28,VN29,VN30,VN31,VN31,VN32,VN33,VN34,VN35,VN36,VN37,VN38,VN39,VN40,VN41,VN42,VN43,VN44,VN45,VN46,VN47,VN48,VN49,VN50), names_to= "Vignetten Position", values_to="Bewertung")

The variables VN.. signify different Vignettes which were evaluated, i want to transform the dataset in such a way, that each row equals one vignette just like so:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3W8B.png)

With my current code this transformation won`t work, before my dataset looked like so:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpwvF.png)

And with said code i transformed it into this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XORhP.png)

i then deleted the secon row of my dataset, sins it's basicaly just the descriptions of each column, but the dataset after transformation looks the same no matter what.